# How to get a html element content

Tags: html, vb.net, web-services

I want to ask if there is a way for me to get like a web element content. What i mean is:
[the site](http://prikachi.com/images.php?images/823/7626823B.png)
[the program](http://prikachi.com/images.php?images/825/7626825M.png)
You don't need to type the site address or where the element is, in need it only in this case(fully empty site with a few words only).
My question is that, wets say that you have a text on a webpage, and you want that text to appear in a textbox...That's it

Comment: Sorry, I simply have no idea what your question is

Comment: My question is that, wets say that you have a text on a webpage, and you want that text to appear in a textbox...That's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this :

```
    Dim We As New System.Net.WebClient()
    textbox1.text = We.DownloadString(_Url)
    We.Dispose()
```